# Does this also define a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The definition of a normal subgroup is: $H$ is said to be a normal subgroup of $G$ if: $h \in H$, and $g \in G$ $\implies$ $ghg^{-1} \in H$

I am wondering if the following also defines a normal subgroup: for all $g \in G$ one has $gHg^{-1} \in H$.

Initially I thought no, since it is not in the form of the definition. However, since $H$ = {$h \in H$: $H$ is a group} then $gHg^{-1} = ghg^{-1}, \forall h \in H$. So wouldn't this formulation be the same as in the definition??? I appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Comment: You mean $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$, not $gHg^{-1}\in G$.

Comment: So stating that $gHg^{-1} \in G$ would be incorrect and so $gHg^{-1}$ is NOT a normal subgroup??

Comment: Do you not know what "$\subset$" and $\in$ **mean**?  $gHg^{-1}$ is subgroup of G not a member so "$gHg^{-1}$\in G$ is **impossible**.  That has nothing to do with whether it is a normal subgroup or not.

Comment: Well, $gHg^{-1}$ is a coset (e.g. it's a subset of G) whereas $ghg^{-1}$ is just a single element of $G$. In general a coset is not a subgroup of the original group.

Comment: Thank you to all. I guess I had a brain fart and wasn't really thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ is a normal subgroup of $G \Leftrightarrow \forall g \in G : gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$. Notice that $gHg^{-1}$ is just the notation we use for the set $\{ ghg^{-1} | h \in H \}$. So this formulation is in fact equivalent to your first definition: $\forall g \in G \forall h \in H : ghg^{-1} \in H$.